# Creating a function that prints the user's input in an "X", from top to bottom

Tags: python

The solution I got currently prints the Input in the X shape from left to right but I needed it from top to bottom.

```
sentence = input("Insert your sentence")

def pattern(str, len):
    for i in range(0, len):
     
        j = len -1 - i
        for k in range(0, len):
         
            if (k == i or k == j):
                print(str[k],
                      end = "")
            else:
                print(end = " ")
         
        print(" ")
        
str = sentence
len = len(str)

pattern(str, len)
```

Using the input "Jonny" as an example with this solution:

```
J   y 
 o n  
  n   
 o n  
J   y
```

The target output would be:

```
J   J 
 o o  
  n   
 n n  
y   y
```

Comment: Hey, a warning about your code.  You probably don't want to overwrite the standard functions `str` and `len` - see https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html.  Use other names for your variables.

Comment: Can you provide a sample output to explain what you mean by "X shape from top to bottom"? Do you want the start of the sentence to be at the top for both diagonals?

Comment: @shriakhilc Edited the question to answer you, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `print(str[k],end = "")` statement, change it into `print(str[i], end="")`.

Full code :

```py
sentence = input("Insert your sentence")
print("\n")

def pattern(str, len):
    for i in range(0, len):
     
        j = len - i - 1
        for k in range(0, len):
         
            if (k == i or k == j):
                print(str[i],
                      end = "")
            else:
                print(end = " ")
         
        print(" ")
        
str = sentence
len = len(str)

pattern(str, len)
```

```
Insert your sentence

j   j 
 o o  
  n   
 n n  
y   y
```

Comment: I knew I was being dumb for some reason ahah Thank you Rohith!

Comment: @Rohith V - Nice job reusing the OP's code.

Comment: yeah it was just a variable change

Answer (score 1):

```py
def pattern2(input_sentence):
    length = len(input_sentence)
    spaces = " " * length
    for i in range(0, length):
        character = input_sentence[i]
        j = length - i - 1
        if (i == j):
            print(spaces[:i] + character)
            continue
        
        output = spaces[:min(i, j)] + character + spaces[min(i, j) + 1:max(i, j)] + character
        print(output)

        
pattern2("Hello there! Good luck learning python!")
```

Output:

```
H                                     H
 e                                   e 
  l                                 l  
   l                               l   
    o                             o    
                                       
      t                         t      
       h                       h       
        e                     e        
         r                   r         
          e                 e          
           !               !           
                                       
             G           G             
              o         o              
               o       o               
                d     d                
                                       
                  l l                  
                   u                   
                  c c                  
                 k   k                 
                                       
               l       l               
              e         e              
             a           a             
            r             r            
           n               n           
          i                 i          
         n                   n         
        g                     g        
                                       
      p                         p      
     y                           y     
    t                             t    
   h                               h   
  o                                 o  
 n                                   n 
!                                     !
```

Comment: I'm sorry for being so ignorant but how do I change the "pattern2" into a user insert instead of a predefined word/sentence?
I tried doing so but to no success

Comment: You need to pass it into the method call. In your original code, `sentence` stores the user input, so you'd call `pattern2(sentence)`. Just make sure you aren't overwriting `str` or `len` before that, because that would cause problems.